# Is there a way to return timestamp after updating timestamp using now()

Tags: php, mysql

I have query like:

```
UPDATE orders SET order_state = $state_id, order_confirmed = now() WHERE order_id = $id LIMIT 1
```

I'm just wondering if there was a function in php or sql that returned the updated timestamp kind of like insert id.

Comment: I think you will have to use insert id and another SELECT query.

Comment: Do you need the timestamp as a confirmation or do you just need the inserted time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid second query, use php's `DateTime Object` and format it, instead of Mysql's `NOW()`

```
$now = new DateTime;
    UPDATE orders SET order_state = $state_id, order_confirmed = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') WHERE order_id = $id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the preferred method of generating a timestamp? php or msql?

Comment: @nkr Sorry, I don't use mysql_* functions. I prefer http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php :)

I don't see any difference... It's just time. But if you need to use it after execution I prefer PHP. I think second query will be more expensible than using DateTime objects.

Comment: @Adam - the choice between PHP and SQL timestamps isn't really that important; they both work fine. What is important is that you try to use the same one consistently through your code, because otherwise you can get issues if the clocks on your PHP and SQL servers are not in sync. For this reason, if your DB has have multiple apps making updates to it or your PHP code is split across multiple servers, you should use the SQL timer, to ensure it's always consistent.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT now() FROM orders LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT now() FROM dual
```